# Notation: subset of powerset containing sets of given cardinality

Tags: notation, set-theory

We are given a set $S$. Is there a generally accepted symbol to denote the set of all subsets with cardinality $\kappa$ of $S$? The notation that comes closest to what I want is the one I found on wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Subsets_of_limited_cardinality,

where they write:

``The set of subsets of $S$ of cardinality less than $\kappa$ is denoted by $\mathcal{P}_{\kappa}(S)$ or $\mathcal{P}_{<\kappa}(S)$. Similarly, the set of non-empty subsets of S might be denoted by  $\mathcal{P}_{\ge1}(S)$''

Is a notation like

$$\mathcal{P}_{=\kappa}(S)$$

generally accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot say that I've seen that notation, but I am likely to understand it from context. A slightly more accepted notation is $[X]^\kappa$.

But the usual advice in this situation is to explicitly define your notation if you feel it might be non-standard, and sometimes even if it is standard it is worth reminding the reader what exactly you mean.

Comment: OK thank you for the information. Now I am confident that explicitly defining my notation is the right thing to do here. Cheers!

Comment: @BJPrim Another notation iw $\binom S\kappa$ though come to think of it I've only seen that used for finite $\kappa$, I'm not sure if it's in use for infinite $\kappa$.